# Stimulsoft Report Chart datasource

Tags: c#, charts, report, pie-chart, stimulsoft

I have a Data Source as show below:

Name - GroupName - Score

GroupName is an array: {G1, G2, G3}

I send this data source to my report and want to show sum and percent of all scores of each group in two Pie Chart to user:

Pie Chart 1:

- G1 > Sum Scores of G1
- G2 > Sum Scores of G2
- G3 > Sum scores of G3

Pie Chart 2:

- G1 > Percent Score of all group
- G2 > Percent Score of all group
- G3 > Percent Score of all group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day i recognized how to do this.

In Stimulsoft reports you can create a datasource of another datasource just in New Data Source select Data from Other Data Source and by aggregate functions create your own columns.

Comment: Could you please post a complete example?